# Не могу подключить университетский прокси Debian 11(407 proxy authentication required)

Tags: debian, proxy

я начинающий в Линуксе. В моем универе мне дали задачу поставить Debian 11 и установить на него через консоль граф.ядро Gnome 40, а потом накатить сверху 20 пакетов. Последние два пункта кажутся мне легкими, но я уже месяц пытаюсь подключиться к прокси нашего универа.Я перепробовал наверное все методы, которые нашел на просторах интернета, и постоянно сталкиваюсь с двумя ошибками, либо 407 proxy authentication required,либо "Сеть недоступна". У нас стоит свой прокси с логином, паролем, прокси хостом и портом.

Пробовал настроить /etc/environment используя и Acquire::http:Proxy и export http_proxy, так же создавал специальный файл в /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/  proxy.sh и тоже конфигурировал его,
конфигурировал /etc/apt/apt.conf файл с настройками, конфигурировал /home/user/.profile

Мой проректор так же пользуется Debian 11 с нашим прокси,однако у него все работает. Он поделился со мной файлами .profile со сточками export http,export https, export ftp proxy,а так же apt.conf с Acquire::hhtp::proxy. скопировав данные строчки в свои файлы я так же получил 407 ошибку.

Так же при установке net версии debian 11, при попытке использования прокси для подключения к зеркалам получаю ошибку

Если кто сталкивался с такой проблемой, подскажите, что делать